# How to upload Files with chinese names in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have learning portal(LMS) where I will upload documents, images, videos etc to create content. If the file being uploaded has a chinese name then it is not getting uploaded. Instead a corrupted file with junk name is uploaded.

For example, I tried to upload a file named **地球科学.jpg**. But on the server I got this file as **åœ°çƒç§‘å­¦.jpg**. Also the uploaded file is corrupted in the server.

I want this file to get upload with the same name on the server.
Because I want to search for these files and reuse later for creating content.

FYI: 
I have XAMPP server installed on Windows XP.
Chinese, Korean, and Japanese language packs installed.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Do you know how this file is being created on the server? Where is your PHP code for this?

Comment: I can confirm it is not your OS. I have the same OS and CJK stuff installed. It's probably your PHP script/env.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK ntfs can't handle some characters on the filesystem. I would suggest to store the file with a generic name.

for example you could create a table with two columns: name and file, as name you save the original name, and as file you set something like md5(name).

Comment: Have you tried it? I just did, and it works. 地球科学.jpg is a perfectly valid NTFS filename.

Comment: am currently not a win user. but could you confirm that its cross-platform-compatible? guess not. same problematic as a customer would upload a file named '--foobar.jpg' to a linux environment (ever tried to delete such a file? ;) )

Comment: Compatible with what platform? I ran it on WindowsXP x86. I don't what other platform WindowsXP runs on. I guess there is Windows for Itanium?

Comment: this solution worked, as suggested by Flask I created a table with 2 columns, name and file and then did all the processes required. Thanks Flask

Answer (score 1):

If you need the name to search for it use a database to store name information and the file location and save the file using your own convention.

Example

```
// sql entry 
original name = 地球科学.jpg
path = /some/place/1.jpg
```

When you search you use the db to locate a given file name and location. Separation storage logic is something common when building image storage solutions not only for naming problems but also for limitations/spped considerations in terms of the number of files that accumulate in folders.

Answer (score 1):

Use `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding` to change character string encoding.

```
// Upload the file into the temp dir
$target_path = "uploadfiles/"; 
$target_path .= $_FILES['fileField']['name']; 

// iconv()
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], iconv("UTF-8", "big5", $target_path))
// mb_convert_encoding()
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], mb_convert_encoding($target_path, "big5", "UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page displaying the form is rendered in utf-8 or higher, usually this does the job, you can also choose to use the `accept-charset` attribute of the form element to indicate the posted data is sent as the specified charset.

Not sure if this all will do the job, let me know.

Comment: I have changed all the pages in utf-8 but no success

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use somekind of database solution, especially when you need to search files later on. With database you can avoid I/O overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must learn/understand what character set the file is in before you can work out how to handle the upload. I'm afraid I'm not too familiar with non-european character sets and don't know which are most widely used.

UTF-8 should be a safe bet to handle almost whatever you care to throw at it. There's some relevant information that could be useful in terms of configuring your application in a post I wrote recently on my blog: [How to Avoid Character Encoding Problems in PHP](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/how-to-avoid-character-encoding-problems-in-php/)